# Sequelize, GraphJS : Cannot read property '2' of null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql-js

I'm using GraphJS with sequelize, when I defined a unique column in the model:

```
const Product = Connection.define('Product', {
    label: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true <--------------
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT(6, 3),
    }
});
```

when I try to **insert** the **second** row with the same **label** :

```
const Mutations = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutations',
    description: 'All Mutations',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            addProduct: {
                type: Product,
                args: {
                    new: {
                        name: 'New product',
                        type: ProductInput
                    }
                },
                resolve(_, args) {
                    return Db.models.Product.create(args.new);
                }
            },
        };
    }
});
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: maybe show the inserting code?

Comment: `const Mutations = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutations',
    description: 'All Mutations',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            addProduct: {
                type: Product,
                args: {
                    new: {
                        name: 'New product',
                        type: ProductInput
                    }
                },
                resolve(_, args) {
                    return Db.models.Product.create(args.new);
                }
            },
        };
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

you dont seem to be the only one having the problem:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6725

https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize/issues/71

do you also use mysql, and if yes which version?

seems to work in some versions, and in some not:

https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize/issues/71#issuecomment-255192417